# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6381. Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery

I have three services, all three of `CELERY_BROKER` are configured as follows:

```
CELERY_BROKER = 'pyamqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@credit-rabbitmq:5673//'
CELERY_RESULT = 'redis://:sOmE__sEcUrE_pAsS@redis:6381'
```

And the celery settings are:

```
# app.celery.py
...
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
CELERY_BROKER = os.getenv('CELERY_BROKER')
app = Celery('app',
             broker=BROKER_URL,
             include=['core.tasks'],
             backend=RESULT_BACKEND,
             namespace='CELERY')

app.conf.task_default_queue = COMMANDS_QUEUE

...
@app.task(bind=True,
          name=TASK_NAME)
def reject_task(self: Task,
                saga_id: int,
                payload: dict):
    # ...
```

But by executing the below command, I encounter the following error:

```
celery -A celery worker -l info -n my-worker
```

My task is run with `my_task.apply_async(data)`

> File
> "/home/saeed/Desktop/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py",
> line 1383, in get_connection
> connection.connect()File "/home/saeed/Desktop/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py",
> line 615, in connect
> raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e)) redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6381.
> Temporary failure in name resolution.File
> "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name
> resolution
>
> ...
>
> connection.connect()   File "/home/saeed/Desktop/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py",
> line 615, in connect
> raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e)) redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6381.
> Temporary failure in name resolution.

This is `redis` docker compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - 6381:6379
    env_file:
      - .env.redis
    networks:
      - carvann_network

networks:
  carvann_network:
    external: true
```

Comment: It works with `my_task.apply(data)` [without async] of a rabbitmq in service one.

Comment: I think docker container is unable to access network

Comment: Did you actually try to connect to your Redis container using the Redis CLI?

Comment: @DejanLekic I think the problem is with Docker. Because when I `ping redis`  I get this error: `ping: redis: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: "redis" should be visible inside Docker infrastructure via the regular 6379 port, and from the outside using the host-ip:6381, where host-ip is the IP of machine running the docker container.